# Change ToolTip in a CRM 2011 View

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to modify a View of the Activities entity so that the Subject field's tooltip displays the body(description) of the email. Below is a picture of the tooltip as it is now, just the subject of the activity.

[image: Tooltip]

I know of this walkthrough, http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/adopt2win/archive/2012/09/14/modifying-tooltips-to-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-fields.aspx#.Uff5a432aUc, and that would work for a Form, but this is not a Form, and Activities don't even have forms.

[image: Activity]

So this is where I'm at. Very little experience with developing CRM as of now, but can follow a trail if given the right direction.

Thanks,

Seeker

Comment: Interesting question. This is definitely not worthy of an answer especially on a bounty question, but if you haven't checked these couple of links out, they may be helpful. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2006/11/17/using-the-attachevent-method-to-show-users-context-sensitive-help.aspx, and http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b5bd5c2-c951-4a26-96d9-db2370ca2c6f/crm-custom-tooltips. I didn't carefully read through them but they may at least provide an idea!

Comment: Thank you for the articles. Both are relevant to a Form instead of a View. The first article may lead to something, but as stated in the article, that trick makes it unsupported, and I'm sure I won't be allowed to implement it.

Comment: I'm very sure that if anything is possible, it will be an unsupported customization. I can guarantee you that part.

Comment: And yeah, the links were for ideas, those are for forms. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way (supported or unsupported) to change the tooltip inside a View.

Comment: I believe that if anyone can find it, it would be the ladies and gentlemen of StackOverflow. You get the answer for today, but I will be putting a bounty on this question when it's eligible, and hopefully someone can find a way to do it. If not, you retain the answer. Hope you don't mind if I keep the bounty points, though. :/ Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Definitely if someone provides an answer you can award it as confirmed answer or gives a bounty, don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

@Guido is correct, there is no supported method of adding tooltips in CRM. The links referenced in comments (since they reference id's in the underlying html) are also **all** unsupported customisations, which means they may well brake after future rollups are released.

Its not impossible per-se.. Supremely difficult though, mostly for the number of places a View can be used.. It can be attached to a form, viewed in a Lookup dialog, seen from the main application window and advanced find dialog, changing the CRM UI wherever the view is used with a single code change is impossible. so you would need to do an unsupported customisation to alter the view for each of these UIs, the cost/benefit ratio means no-one in their right mind would attempt it!

Just add description as a column in the View :)